# Converting linear equation of two variables to slope intercept form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

How do I convert the general form of a linear equation of two variables to slope intercept form?

> More precisely, beginning with the form $ax + by + c = 0$

I have tried rearranging this for $y$, however, I am having difficulties with this. My idea is the following: use the substitution $c = -(x + y)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Solve for $y$, not $c$. You must also assume $b\ne 0$.

Comment: I see $ax + by + c = 0$ then $y = \frac{ax}{b}  + \frac{c}{b}$, now can I substitute $c = -(x + y)$?  Also, does $a, b$ somehow represent a perpendicular line (like the normal vector) to the line the equation represents?

Comment: $ax+by+c=0$ should instead become $y = -\frac{ax}b - \frac cb$.

Comment: @peterwhy So the result is $y = -\frac{ax}{b} - \frac{c}{b}$ and when I substitute in for $c$, $y = -\frac{ax}{b} - \frac{-(x+y)}{b}$.  Not really sure what's going on with the last term on the right and what it means.  Do you know?

Comment: Why do you want to substitute $c=-(x+y)$ anyway?

Comment: So $c$ should be a multiple of $b$, $nb$ to express the y intercept?  Just trying to figure out what $c$ represents

Comment: The $y$-intercept is exactly $-\frac cb$ from the general form. I guess $c$ alone does not have a clear meaning, as the general form can be scaled by any non-zero constant $k$: $$ax+by+c = 0 \iff (ka)x+(kb)y+(kc) = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

We can rearrange the general form for $y$ as follows:

$$ax + by + c = 0 \space \iff \space by = -ax - c \space \iff \space y = -\frac{a}{b}x - \frac{c}b $$

Therefore the desired answer is $y = -\frac{a}{b}x - \frac{c}b$.

The interpretation of this formula is that our $y$-intercept is $-\frac{c}{b}$ and the gradient of line is $-\frac{a}{b}$. As the gradient is negative, we can conclude that this is a downward-sloping line.

---

*Note: as we are dividing by $b$, we must assume that $b \neq 0$ for the above solution to hold. If $b = 0$, then we have $ax + c = 0$ which rearranges to $x = \frac{-c}{a}$* for $a \neq 0$.